# Prevent javascript from running onClick when a contained element is clicked (knockout)

Tags: knockout.js, jsfiddle, single-page-application

With knockout I have the following:

```
<!-- ko foreach: data.folders -->
    <div class="study-box">
        <input class="study-box-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This gives me a list of divs with checkboxes inside.  I've registered the following event handler to study-boxes:

```
var bindEventToList = function (rootSelector, selector, callback, eventName) {
        var eName = eventName || 'click';
        $(rootSelector).on(eName, selector, function () {
            var folder = ko.dataFor(this);
            callback(folder);
            return false;
        });
    };

bindEventToList(view, '.study-box', gotoDetails);
```

So, when a study-box is clicked, goToDetails is triggered.

The problem with this is that even if the containing checkbox is clicked, the event is triggered.  I don't want this to happen.  Checkboxes have their own bindings:

```
<input class="study-box-checkbox" type="checkbox" data-bind="visible: checkboxIsVisible(), attr: { value: setId() }, attrIf: { id: 'study-box-checkbox-soft', _if: (softCheckboxIsVisible() && isSelected() == false) }, checked: isSelected" />
```

I think an option is to position the checkbox outside of the div but then it becomes a matter of positioning the checkbox on top of each div, which seems far from trivial.

How can this be fixed?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/79/

Comment: JSFiddle appears to be down at the moment, but it sounds like you have a click handler on the div and on the input? If so, have you looked at [`event.stopPropogation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a custom binding like this in the past when this needs to be coupled with the `checked` binding on an element:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopPropagation = {
    init: function(element) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "click", function(e) {
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/2yYMY/

If you are are using it with a normal `click` binding, then you can just also specify `clickBubble: false` in the binding.